# Matching a word to first 3 letters of any word in a list

Tags: python, list, textmatching

I have a list of key words (in csv format), which all entries coming into to my database should match. I am trying to write a python code whereby if an entered word matches the first 3 or more letters as any word in a list.

For example:

if my word is ora

the list of words:

```
  orange
  yellow
  blue
  green
  purple
```

I want to assign the word ora to the key orange. Is there some way of doing this on python?

Another example is if the word is orazzz, I still want it to pick up that the first 3 letters match orange and assign it to that key.

I would like to put it into an if statement if possible

Comment: Show the if statement and look at a data structure called a Trie

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this with Set.

```
word=set('orange')
db_entry=set('orngesdksd')

if len(word.intersection(db_entry))>=5:
    print(word.intersection(db_entry))
```

Output:

```
{'n', 'e', 'o', 'g', 'r'}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, sorry I've changed the question though (I've just realised what I was originally trying to do won't actually work)

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary for lookups and a try catch to handle th enot found situation.

```
keywords = ('orange yellow blue green purple'.split())

keys = dict((w[0:3], w) for w in keywords)

entry = 'orzazzz'
try:
    key = keys[entry[0:3]]
    print( 'Entered value {0} matches key {1}'.format(entry, key) )
except KeyError:
    print( 'Entered value {0} does not match and keyword.'.format(entry) )
```

Comment: Thank you - I'm getting an error where it is giving a 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' at the  ' after  {1}

Comment: @user9645302 This uses the print statement. For Python 3, add parentheses. Next time specify Python 3 in your question and you won't get Python 2 answers.

Comment: @user9645302 - yes, I must transition to Python 3 myself.

Comment: Sorry about that. Where do I add in the parentheses sorry?